# MVC Convert @Html.PagedListPager into Ul and LI tags

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

So I have a paging code in my view, so how do I convert this into "ul & li" tags

> @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("DisplayTTs",
> "TTCreator", new { page = page, SearchTT = ViewBag.searchTxt }))

> ```
>              <nav aria-label="...">
>             <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
>               <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
>                 <span class="page-link">1</span>
>               </li>
>               <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
>               <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
>             </ul>
>           </nav>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When I came across a problem similar to yours I found the information on [this site](https://www.igniteui.com/help/iggrid-paging) very helpful.
I hope you find what you want there.